# C# powerpoint edit smartart text

Tags: c#, com, powerpoint, office-interop

I am currently trying to replace some text in a powerpoint smartart object. I can get the text but I am unable to set the text value even when a lot of documents make it seem very easy.

I am using

```
shp.SmartArt.AllNodes[i].TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = shapeString;
```

to set the text string but I am coming up with an error no matter what function I use

```
shp.SmartArt.AllNodes[i].TextFrame2.DeleteText();
```

returns the same error message as the other message. I may need to make the powerpoint visible but for some reason when I make it visible it disappears. (anti-virus?)

I can replace text in the powerpoint with standard text boxes so I am trying to repeat the steps for smartart with no success.

> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>   at Microsoft.Office.Core.TextRange2.set_Text(String pbstrText)
>   at *.Form1.BtnStart_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
>   *\Form1.cs:line 414
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
>
> mscorlib
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.4075.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>
> System.Windows.Forms
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.4042.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_0.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> System
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.4001.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c> 561934e089/System.dll
>
> System.Drawing
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0> __b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>
> System.Configuration
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>
> System.Core
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.4075.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b> 77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
>
> System.Xml
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b7> 7a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>
> Microsoft.CSharp
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.CSharp/v4.0_4.0.0> .0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.CSharp.dll
>
> System.Dynamic
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Dynamic/v4.0_4.0.0.0> __b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Dynamic.dll
>
> Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
>   Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.4075.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
>
> CustomMarshalers
>   Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/CustomMarshalers/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/CustomMarshalers.dll
>
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
>   Assembly Version: 15.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 15.0.4569.1507
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint/15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll
>
> office
>   Assembly Version: 15.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 15.0.4613.1000
>   CodeBase: 
>   file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/office/15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/office.dll
>
> System.Dynamic.DynamicAssembly
>   Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
>   Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0
>   CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Dynamic/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Dynamic.dll

Not sure where to go next.

*************Documentation/Reference*************

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/presentation/smartart

```
//Open a PowerPoint Presentation
IPresentation pptxDoc = Presentation.Open("SampleDocument.pptx");

//Traverse through shape in the first slide.
foreach (IShape shape in pptxDoc.Slides[0].Shapes)
{
if (shape is ISmartArt)
{
//Traverse through all nodes inside SmartArt
foreach (ISmartArtNode mainNode in (shape as ISmartArt).Nodes)
{
if (mainNode.TextBody.Text == "Old Content")
//Change the node content
mainNode.TextBody.Paragraphs[0].TextParts[0].Text = "New Content";
}
}
}

//Save the Presentation.
pptxDoc.Save("SmartArt.pptx");

//Close the Presentation.
pptxDoc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using openxml to work around this issue. I am unfortunatly switching between openxml and interop until I can find a better fix.

```
using (PresentationDocument doc = PresentationDocument.Open(textBox1.Text, true))
{
       PresentationPart pp = doc.PresentationPart;
       SlidePart sp1 = pp.SlideParts.ToList<SlidePart>()[0];
       foreach (DiagramDataPart ddp in sp1.DiagramDataParts.ToList<DiagramDataPart>())
       {
             DataModelRoot dmr = ddp.DataModelRoot;
             List<PointList> pl = dmr.Descendants<PointList>().ToList();
             foreach (PointList item in pl)
             {
                    List<Point> ps = item.Descendants<Point>().ToList();
                    foreach (Point p in ps)
                    {
                          if (p.InnerText.Equals("_HELLO_"))
                          {
                                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph para = p.TextBody.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph>();
                                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run run1 = para.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run>();
                                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text text1 = run1.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text>();
                                text1.Text = "World";
                                var textreplacement = p.InnerText;
                          }
                    }
              }
        }
        doc.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Interop, but you might try testing first whether a node **has** text first before changing it. Some SmartArt variants have text nodes that can't be set programmatically, so trying to add text on them will always fail. This is working to set SmartArt text here, using this VBA:

```
If ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).SmartArt.AllNodes(X).TextFrame2.HasText Then
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).SmartArt.AllNodes(X).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Text"
End If
```

Comment: It may have to do with the fact that I do not have an active slide selected. I believe ppt is running in the background while I am working on this.

Comment: PowerPoint only needs to display an active slide if you're using a selection. If you use ranges, the presentation doesn't need to display at all.